# Unity for Hololens- lacking the player? Windows store?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

**The Problem**
After installing Unity(5.6.0f3) and creating an example project, I go to the Edit-> Project Settings-> Quality and on the Quality Settings instead of this picture
[image: Quality Settings]
I got only the Arrow one (not the green one-Windows Store Logo)

Also in Edit->Project Settings->Player I can see that there are settings for PC, MAC & Linux but not the Windows Store one

**The situation**

In the PC I am working on, I have had Windows Studio 2017 community installed previously. I have not installed the Hololens Emulator because my PC only has 2 cores (not 4 as required).　I wonder if this could be the cause?

Does installing the Holographic templates only solve this? (I am planning to continue development on another PC expressly bought for this but would like to do as much as I can on my PC)

Or do I have to install another thing (Windows Store??) for Unity to work as the tutorials?

Thanks for any help, very much appreciated

Comment: Are you on Windows 10?

Comment: Found out the solution  File>Build Settings>Double Click Windows Store>Download.(The window store files)